# IMG not showing above background color?

Tags: css, html, z-index, background-color

I have 3 divs, each with a z-index higher than the previous and all overlain on eachother.

The bottom div has an image, the next div has a background-color with opacity:0.7 and the topmost div has another image.  The problem is the top-most image also appears underneath the background-color of the div beneath it, in Chrome, FF and IE.

Is there a workaround to allow the top most image be displayed on top as it should?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could just replace the background-color with a plain img.

Comment: hmm, this didn't work until I changed to position:fixed for the topmost div. Curious.

Comment: actually not curious - I just found out for z-index to function properly it requires the position rule to be explicitly set in css.

Comment: If you use fixed, then when the page scrolls, that element will be at the same place (ie, it won't scroll with the rest of the page). Position: static; is the default value.